# Teechart slow after updating to delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, vcl, teechart, delphi-xe6

I have recently updated my delphi from XE4 to XE6, but it is extremely slow to plot points using the TPointSeries series. I noticed the points to be anti-aliased, so I disabled that using `chart_radar.Canvas := TTeeCanvas3D.Create`. The anti-aliasing effect is gone, but the drawing of points remains slow.

Any idea what causes this change in efficiency and how to speed up drawing the points?

Comment: Can you give us a simple repro program to investigate?